# QGIS: Turning a string into "relative" hyperlink

Tags: qgis, string, hyperlink

I have a few columns in my shapefile that to refer to certain folders and files (PDF, JPG etc.). Because these are interesting in a form for each object, so that people can open them. I want to make a "relative" hyperlink to those files, and by relative I mean relative to where the shapefile itself is.

For example:

```
xxx/Shapefile folder
xxx/shapefile folder/Folder 1/File 1
xxx/shapefile folder/Folder 1/File 2
xxx/shapefile folder/Folder 1/File 2
```

In the atrribute table is this: `/Folder 1/File 2`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three ways how you can achieve this:

**

Update: if you want the fields created in both solutions to update automatically, create a virtual field insted of a regular field with the field calculator, see here for details: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#creating-a-virtual-field

**First version:**

You can define a custom variable in your layer properties, in the variables tab. There, create a new variable named, let's say, `layer_path` and paste as value the filepath where your layer is stored - like e.g. D:/Data/Shapefiles/Polygons/

In the attribute table, than create a new field, let's call it `img_path` with the field-calculator. To define to content of the field, use an expression that includes the variable you defined before, adding the specific location of your pictures, e.g. if you have the information about Folder 1/File 2 stored in a field called `pictures`, than you could use this expression:

```
@layer_path  ||  "pictures"
```

Whenever the path changes, you just have to change the variable once and than update the created field in your attribute table with the field calculator and the same expression as above.

**Second version:**

Update: alternatively, use the pre-defined `project_path` variable - you can use this in case your project is stored in the same directory as your shapefile. Use the expression `file_path(path)` to get only the path, without filename.

**Third version:**

Use the expression layer_property( ) for creating a new field in the field calculator. Selct the layer whose path you want to take as an input (in the following expample it's called 'my_layer', it's just a dummy, when you select the layer in the expression editor, the name will look something like 'my_layer_c2175115_adbb_408d_8c29_ab7974543fd7'), the second argument 'path' has to be written exactely like this:

```
layer_property( 'my_layer', 'path')
```

In this case, you don't have to define a custom variable. However, the output of the above expression will be the whole path include the filename like my_geopackage.gpkg - so you have to use another expression to get rid of that. You could add a replace( ) expression to that above:

```
replace(layer_property( 'my_layer', 'path'),'string_to_be_deleted','')
```

Again, replace 'string_to_be_deleted' with those characters that should be deleted from your path.

Comment: Thank you these solutions though one thing is missing that I will add in my edit as soon, as the shapefile is being changed somewhere and or is added to a geodatabase the layer path, aka that column should change immeadely even though  the files are technically not there.the files may not technically not be there.

Comment: Updated my answer to automatically update the path of the layer. However, not sure why you use that, normally it doesn't make sense to remove files that you have embedded as a layer.